# Silverlight control does not maintain state, reloads

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a web application where I have a Silverlight control. The application displays several tabs inside a browser window (we are using IE 8 and that is the only browser we are supporting). The application displays the Silverlight control on tabs dynamically, based on the data. So, if I have a window where I see 3 tabs, then it may be in one tab, or it may be on all three of the tabs and so on. The problem is that we do not have control of the tabs and every single time the client clicks on one of the tabs, if there is a Silverlight control there then it is initialized like if the window is being open the first time. 
The problem with that is that the client can make changes on the control (not the data display), like scrolling through the data in the control. Those changes are lost because the control is initialized and we don't want that. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: If you can't stop the HTML page from removing the elements that contain the Silverlight plugin, then I'm not sure what you can do. You _could_ store any relevant GUI information in isolated storage and reconstruct the state whenever the plugin is re-initialized.

Comment: Yes, I had thought about cookies, is that what you had in mind as well?

Comment: Not browser cookies so much as [Silverlight Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).